# displayDialogAsync is not returning success message handler to source page

Tags: office-js

Regarding displayDialogAsync having below issue:

1. We used to displayDialogAsync in showTaskpane event and once clicking of dialog it was returning successful message to home page from where it is called.
2. Now we are trying to use the same dialog box with ExecuteAction event and click of any event in dialog box success message is not returning to home page. It is in open state once click any button event.

Tried with below sample code :

**Dialog.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
    <script>
        Office.initialize = function () {
            $('#button1').click(one);
            $('#button2').click(two);
        };

        function one()
        {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent("Picked 1");                
        }

        function two() {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent("Picked 2");
        }
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="ms-font-xxl ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semilight">Pick a number</p>
    <button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" id="button1">
        <span class="ms-Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--plus"></i></span>
        <span class="ms-Button-label" id="button1-text">1</span>
        <span class="ms-Button-description" id="button1-desc">Number 1</span>
    </button>
    <button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" id="button2">
        <span class="ms-Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--plus"></i></span>
        <span class="ms-Button-label" id="button2-text">2</span>
        <span class="ms-Button-description" id="button2-desc">Number 2</span>
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Command.ts**

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
 * See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
 */
import {SetRuntimeVisibleHelper,SetStartupBehaviorHelper,updateRibbon, openDialog} from '../utilities/office-apis-helpers';

var clickEvent;
(function () {
  Office.initialize = function (reason) {
     // If you need to initialize something you can do so here.
  };
})();

function getLoginfirst(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) {
 
  clickEvent = event;
  localStorage.setItem("isEvent",event.source.id.toString());    
   updateRibbon();  
  openDialog(); 
}

export function showNotification(text)
{   
    clickEvent.completed();
}


function getLogout(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) {

  localStorage.setItem("isEvent",event.source.id.toString());  
   SetRuntimeVisibleHelper(false);  
   updateRibbon();
 
  event.completed();
}


export function getGlobal() { 
  return (typeof self !== "undefined") ? self :
    (typeof window !== "undefined") ? window : 
    (typeof global !== "undefined") ? global :
    undefined;
}

const g = getGlobal() as any;

// the add-in command functions need to be available in global scope

g.getLoginfirst = getLoginfirst;
g.getLogout=getLogout;
```

**Manifest Part:**

```
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="CustomFunctionsRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>

 <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>


 <Runtimes>
<Runtime resid="Contoso.SharedRuntime.Url" lifetime="long" />
</Runtimes>

  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.LoginButton">
                <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="Contoso.LoginButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                     <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="Contoso.LoginButton.Label" />
                     <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.LoginButton.Icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.LoginButton.Icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.LoginButton.Icon80" />
                  </Icon>

                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">                  
                    <FunctionName>getLoginfirst</FunctionName>
                  </Action>                                                                 
                </Control>  

<bt:Url id="Contoso.SharedRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
```

**Office-api-helpers.ts**

```
var dialog;

function dialogCallback(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {

        // In addition to general system errors, there are 3 specific errors for 
        // displayDialogAsync that you can handle individually.
        switch (asyncResult.error.code) {
            case 12004:
                //showNotification("Domain is not trusted");
                break;
            case 12005:
                //showNotification("HTTPS is required");
                break;
            case 12007:
                //showNotification("A dialog is already opened.");
                break;
            default:
                //showNotification(asyncResult.error.message);
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        /*Messages are sent by developers programatically from the dialog using office.context.ui.messageParent(...)*/
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, messageHandler);

        /*Events are sent by the platform in response to user actions or errors. For example, the dialog is closed via the 'x' button*/
        // dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, eventHandler);
    }
}


function messageHandler(arg) {    
    showNotification(arg.message);
    dialog.close();
}

export function openDialog() {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/Dialog.html",
        { height: 50, width: 50 }, dialogCallback);
}
```

Comment: Please share the manifest for the ExecuteAction.

Comment: @RickKirkham..I have updated part of the manifest file...hope that is enough or please let me know anything required...

Comment: I don't think you can use the same taskpane.html file for both the taskdpane and the FunctionFile. Create a separate function.html file that has no UI and loads a function.js file. Copy your logic to the function.js file. For more see, [Add the functionfile element](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands#step-5-add-the-functionfile-element).

Comment: Yes i understood. Then how can we achieve the  scenario like it should load UI controls along with that dialog box should return success token messages on ExecuteAction method with shared runtime. It would be better if you can re-write manifest file which i have already attached to achieve the scanario...

Comment: @RickKirkham.. I have updated with latest work around as per you suggestion but still am facing the same issue. When trying to click any button 1 or 2 nothing happened..

Comment: @RickKirkham... can you please update any help or do we need to share any repo project to re-produce the issue?.... as we have been working this on past one month...